# NVM: Combining version node 12.18.0 with npm 7

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have a strange behaviour with nvm on macOS. Currently I have installed node version 12.18.0 together with npm version 6.14.4.
Today I wanted to update my npm so I just ran `npm install -g npm`. When I submitted the command nvm installed node version 12.20.1 together with npm 7.16.0.
So now I have the combinations of node 12.18.0 with npm 6 and 12.21.1 with npm 7.
I wouldn't mind that case but there are two problems which occur now:

1. When I set the new node version as default and restart the terminal it doesn't change. It stays at the system version (which is 10).
2. When I manually change the node version with `nvm use default` I get this warning: `(node:55181) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental`

Isn't it possible to install the combination of node 12.18.0 and npm 7? And which node/npm version doesn't print out the warning?

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the error. I had a `.npmrc` file in my home directory and in this the version 12.20.1 was set. When I deleted the file I could get the combination of node 12.18.0 and npm 7.